# C++ QTextDocument::contentsChange() signal provides invalid input data

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently developing a simple oline plain text editor for my university class. I use `QTextDocument::contentsChange(index, charsRemoved, charsAdded)` signal to determine changes made to document by `QPlainTextEdit` and send them to the server.
But sometimes arguments, `charsRemoved` and `charsAdded` give invalid values.

E.g. when I insert text with Ctrl+V in the middle of the editor's text then proper charsAdded info is reported (`charsRemoved == 0 && charsAdded == <inserted_text_length>` ). But if I insert text to the zero'th index, right before the first character, then invalid data is given (`charsRemoved == <previous_editors_text_size> + 1 && charsAdded == <new_editors_text_size> + 1`). However, if I input a single character by typing it via keyboard and my cursor is placed at the beginning of the editor, signal correctly reports reports `charsRemoved == 0 && charsAdded == 1`

Moreover, when I change my text input language by hitting Ctrl+Shift or when I use Alt+Tab while cursor is placed anywhere in `QPlainTextEdit` window, 
then signal `QTextDocument::contentsChange()` is emmited twice and it reports that `charsRemoved == <current_editors_text_size> + 1 &&
charsAdded == <previous_editors_text_size>`

Is it a bug or otherwise how can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this bug have been reported since qt 4, but was never fixed. 
The latest bug report I could find is [this one](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49062).

For the double signal emission, consider that this signal should be used to report both changes in text contents and format. So maybe those combinations of keys trigger two signals, once for the text and once for the change in the input mode. But this is just my supposition.